# PHP code with check box arrays does not work in real site but works in local host

Tags: php, html

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

I have a very strange problem with a PHP code, using checkbox arrays.
It is a simple checkbox code in a real site in Russian language, where I help to my frend to fix:
http://astrabis.ru/teoria/test2.php

The host has the PHP Version 5.3.13.

**But this code, YES, works in my local PC (Windows 7, with installed Xamp Appache) PHP Version 5.6.3.** I has been installed the PHP server to debug the problem that I describe here.

Problem description. The check boxes in the file test2.php is shown perfectly on a browser, but when I check some of them and press Submit, the server does not move any data to testrez2.php file that processes the data.

Details.
In file test2.php there are three arrays of check boxes: vata[] pita[] kapha[]
The test2.php code fragments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" /><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
...
</head>
...
<form action="http://www.astrabis.ru/teoria/testrez2.php" method="post">
...
<table cellspacing="1px">
<tbody>
<tr><td rowspan="3">????</td><td><input name="vata[]" type="checkbox" value="2">???????, ??????????; ???????????, ??????????? ?? ???????? ?????????, ???????????? ????????, ??????? ? ??? ?????? ? ? ??? ??????.</td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="pita[]" type="checkbox" value="2">???????????, ?????????????????, ????????????, ?????? ????, ????? ???????. ???????????? ???. ???????????? ???????? ? ????, ???? ??????? ??????? ???? ?? ????????????????? ????????.</td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="kapha[]" type="checkbox" value="2">?????????, ??????, ??????????, ?? ???????????? ???????.</td>
...
...
<tr><td rowspan="3">?????</td><td><input name="vata[]" type="checkbox" value="2">??????????? ? ????? ? ???????????.</td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="pita[]" type="checkbox" value="2">??????????? ? ?????????? ???????????, ?????? ?????????.</td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="kapha[]" type="checkbox" value="2">??????????? ? ????????????? - ????????,???????? ? ?.?.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The file of the result processing, testrez2.php, has some simple matematic, but I added some debug code to see the input data and other info
The testrez2.php code fragments:

```
...
<?php
echo "<br>vata : ";
print_r(array_values($_POST['vata']));
echo "<br>pita : ";
print_r(array_values($_POST['pita']));
echo "<br>kapha : ";
print_r(array_values($_POST['kapha']));

$x=0;
$y=0;
$z=0;

if (isset($_POST['vata']))
{$x=array_sum($_POST['vata']);}

if (isset($_POST['pita']))
{$y=array_sum($_POST['pita']);}

if (isset($_POST['kapha']))
{$z=array_sum($_POST['kapha']);}

$sum=$x+$y+$z;

//debug
echo "<br>x : $x";
echo "<br>y : $y";
echo "<br>z : $z";
echo "<br>sum : $sum";
```

More of that, historically, I started to debug another file from the site and added the same code in a file testrez3.php, (it is activated by test3.php of the same real url). It is the same debug printing code that is shown in the file testrez2.php above.

The pair test3.php and testrez3.php are worked several days and stopped with the same problem!

I also shanged the method from POST to GET in files  test2.php  testrez2.php
(). I wanted to see in the address line of my browser Chrome that the checkbox data is really sent to the server. It is sent! But the testrez2.php  also does not receive any data.

See below the match of two "gets": real site and my PC local host

localhost/astrabis/astrabis.ru/test/testrez2.php?vata%5B%5D=2&pita%5B%5D=2&kapha%5B%5D=2&vata%5B%5D=2&pita%5B%5D=2&kapha%5B%5D=2

astrabis.ru/teoria/testrez2.php?vata%255B%255D=2&pita%255B%255D=2&kapha%255B%255D=2&vata%255B%255D=2&pita%255B%255D=2&kapha%255B%255D=2

Comment: Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/astrabis/astrabis.ru/docs/teoria/testrez2.php on line 23 - Same on line 26 and 28 of testrez2.php. Show us lines 23, 26, 28

Comment: 'code' 22 echo "<br>vata : ";
      'code' 23 print_r(array_values($_POST['vata']));
    24 echo "<br>pita : ";
    25 print_r(array_values($_POST['pita']));
    26 echo "<br>kapha : ";
    27 print_r(array_values($_POST['kapha']));

Comment: Marina, thank you for the answer. I now regarding the Warning. This is the core of the problem. In the **print_r(array_values($_POST['vata']));** that I shown above, the ''vata" does not exists because the server does not send it to the testrez2.php file. And as the result, the $_POST is empty and array_values print out the warning. This cod I added specially to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the difference:

```
pita%5B%5D=2
```

locally vs:

```
pita%255B%255D=2
```

if you urldecode `pita%5B%5D`you will get pita[] but the other one is double urlencoded, if you decode it once you will get `pita%5B%5D`. That is your problem. You should check where that double urlencode comes from. 
I don't see anything in the code you posted so maybe some server setting.

Comment: Christian, thank you for the answer. I also saw the difference. And I showed the line from the code: <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />

Comment: And I thought that the encoding is the problem. I changed the code to UTF8 encoding (but without change the charset parameter. It did not help. Please give me some toward, I really do not know what to do

Comment: Christian, more of then. The **pita%255B%255D=2** data is sent from the client (Chrome) and you simple can see the HTML code by "View page source" command. I did that and I have no any idea.

Comment: This is unrelated to the charset encoding.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php and urldecode
This is what happens. It has to be something on your server doing that.

Comment: Christian@, I read carefully your advice, but I do not understand why it is the server's problem, because you point yarly that GET message from Chrom (client) is differ from the localhost one. And also the messahe is incorrect. Now I requested from a owner of the site to modify the FORM in test2.php, adding 'enctype = text/plan' and next try will be ' = application/x-www...'

Comment: My test by changing '<form action="http://localhost/astrabis/astrabis.ru/test/testrez2.php" method="post">' to 
'<form action="http://localhost/astrabis/astrabis.ru/test/testrez2.php" method="post"  enctype="text/plain">​' and after then to
'<form action="http://localhost/astrabis/astrabis.ru/test/testrez2.php" method="post"  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">​' did not fix the problem. Please help